# JQuery .each loop not working when iterating through elements with dynamic class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

The .each loop below doesn't work when I use variables to search for elements with the same class name as the variable's value. The result; No alert occurs.

```
var NameString = $("#StoreInputs").val();
var NameArray = NameString.split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < NameArray.length; i++){
$('.' + NameArray[i]).each(function(n, obj){
  alert(obj.val());
    });
}
```

Comment: log the value of `NameArray[i]` and check what is logged.. my assumption is there could be a leading space... check if there is any error in the console..

Comment: try to trim the class name `'.' + $.trim(NameArray[i])`

Comment: hey, thank you a lot for your suggestion. This, particularly was not the issue though as there are no leading nor trailing spaces :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj` is the raw input, to use `.val()` you have to `$(obj)` it:

```js
var NameString = $("#StoreInputs").val();
var NameArray = NameString.split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < NameArray.length; i++){
  $('.' + NameArray[i]).each(function(n, obj){
    alert($(obj).val());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="StoreInputs" value="cl2,cls1"/>
<input class="cls1 cls2" value="in1"/>
<input class="cls2" value="in2"/>
<input class="cls1 cls3" value="in3"/>
```

For information `obj` == `this`.

Comment: You pointed out the fact that i needed to wrap the obj in jquery tags. And that was the issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `.each()` loop:

Instead of

```
$('.' + NameArray[i]).each(function(n, obj){
  alert(obj.val());
});
```

Try

```
$('.' + NameArray[i]).each(function(index,value){
  alert($(value).val());
});
```

**EDIT :-**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/08v02y8a/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var NameString = $("#StoreInputs").val();
var NameArray = NameString.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < NameArray.length; i++) {
    //trim the class name to remove any leading spaces
    $('.' + $.trim(NameArray[i])).each(function (n, obj) {
        //obj is a dom element reference, so doesn't have the val() method
        //so wrap it using jQuery object
        alert($(obj).val());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach to this

```
$('.' + NameArray[i]).each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

You are looping to each html and not to a javascript array object.  There are two type of `each` in jquery the **[jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** and the **[.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**

The ***jQuery.each*** if for the arrays, if you want to loop to all the elements of our **NameArray**

```
jQuery.each( NameArray, function( index, value ) {
    alert(value);
});
```

and the ***.each*** one if for the looping of html elements given the identifiers you specified

```
$('.' + NameArray[i]).each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Here is a **[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmkzmonr/)** to demonstrate it

```
<input type="text" id="classlist" value="class1,class2" /> 
<ul>
    <li class="class1">TEXT 1</li>
    <li class="class2">TEXT 2</li>
    <li class="class3">TEXT 3</li>
    <li class="class3">TEST 4</li>
</ul>
<div id="eachContent">
    Contents retrieved using .each
</div>
<div id="jqueryeachContent">
    Contents retrieved using jQuery.each
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      // Using jQuery.each looping of array
      var nameArray = jQuery('#classlist').val().split(',');
      jQuery.each( nameArray, function( index, value ) {
          $('.' + value).each(function(){ 
               jQuery("#eachContent").html(jQuery("#eachContent").html() + '<br>' + $(this).text());
          }); 
      });
      // using .each looping of elements
       $('.class3').each(function(){ 
           jQuery("#jqueryeachContent").html(jQuery("#jqueryeachContent").html() + '<br>' + $(this).text());
       });
    });
</script>
```